# Creating new instance of object in loop to add in list

Tags: java, web-services, object

I am trying to add the object (JavaBean) into the list.

```
     MyWebServiceRequest mywebService = new MyWebServiceRequest();
     MyRequestType type= new MyRequestType ();

       for(int i=0; i< 9; i++){
           type.setA(someDynamicValue);
           type.setB(someDynamicValue);
           mywebService.add(type);
       }
```

This creates only one object of (type), so it add same object 9 times with same data.

```
 MyWebServiceRequest mywebService = new MyWebServiceRequest();
   for(int i=0; i< 9; i++){
           MyRequestType type= new MyRequestType ();
           type.setA(someDynamicValue);
           type.setB(someDynamicValue);
           mywebService.add(type);
       }
```

This creates multiple objects, add 9 diff object with diff values .

What if (for loop) create hundreds of objects instead of 9 in single loop , each and every time a request is made?
So its dump in memory right?

How to avoid this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: clarify you question , its not understandable !!  what u mean by "getting the exact request" and "request element"

Comment: when u add MyRequestType type= new MyRequestType (); in loop , a new object is created for 9 times .

Comment: when i dont Create new object in loop, the object is added 9 times but data is same for all objects eventhough if diff data is setted .when i put new Object in loop , it add 9 objects to list with diff data. Will it affect the efficiency of memory? What if my for loop create hundreds of object? I am often gettin outofmemory PermGen space error.

Comment: please accept my praise to all answerers... I have tried to read the question for 5 times and still cannot understand what he is trying to ask

Comment: @user1665651 , you want one object or 9 different objects..??  , does the data has to be same for all other 9 objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this

```
 MyWebServiceRequest mywebService = new MyWebServiceRequest();
   MyRequestType type= new MyRequestType ();

   for(int i=0; i< 9; i++){
       type.setA(1);
       type.setB(2);
       mywebService.add(type);
   }
```

The line  `mywebService.add(type);` adds the object into list , no matter its state is changed or not or it is the same object. Because its a list and not a Map which do not allow duplicates.

So the count goes to 10 , now when you do

```
 MyWebServiceRequest mywebService = new MyWebServiceRequest();


   for(int i=0; i< 9; i++){
       MyRequestType type= new MyRequestType ();
       type.setA(1);
       type.setB(2);
       mywebService.add(type);
   }
```

The code now makes a new object and add to list , but every object is different .
The only difference in two snippets is , the Objects in the second snippet are not same , but in the first snippet its same but added 10 times.

Comment: Thanks anshulkatta, I want to know will it affect my application performance by creating more objects in the memory. Is there a way to avoid this.

Comment: If your requirement is to store the same object 10 times in List , then i think its waste of memory , because you are saving the same object evrytime , but if you want to have 10 different objects with same values , that is also a waste though :P , its all on your requirement. What is your requirement. ??

Answer (score 1):

Because, when you place the object creation outside the loop, only one object will be created. Hence, only that object is added to the list, though you are trying to add it 9 times.

1. A new object is created
   Loop Starts
2. Some values are set into the object.
3. Object is added to the List.(i.e, referenced in the list)

In second iteration when the values are changed, it is changed in the object created in Step 1 which is referred in the list 10 times.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks rajkumar, The reason for raising this question is , i get memery leaks in my application. If i make object as null inside loop for every new object created, will it affect the next object created. For eg, loop{ new myObject; myObject=null;}

Answer (score 1):

```
MyWebServiceRequest mywebService = new MyWebServiceRequest();
for(int i=0; i< 9; i++){
   MyRequestType type= new MyRequestType ();
   type.setA(1);
   type.setB(2);
   mywebService.add(type);
   type = null;
}
```

Setting null to the variable 'type' as shown above will not have any impact on memory. Because, the object is already referred to your list. Hence, even if you set null to the variable 'type' it will not have any impact to memory leaks.

Please give an overview of the application and the issue you face if you are facing the issue in a real time application.

Comment: My Application is all getting user details from web service and displaying in jsps. web service is app1(DAO) and struts2&jsp App2. i send xml request to web service and get back the response. I iterate the response using the POJO/Bean class as explained above code, add all the objects in list. So if i clear the list, will all references will be GC'd. What to do now. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, if the list is cleared, all the objects will be available for garbage collection and memory will be freed. Anyhow, once the response is processed and sent to the Client machine the memory will be freed up. Are you facing memory issues while iterating through the list of user details received from Web service (app1)?